# How to make a multiple scanned image readable

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scanning, noise

I'm trying to make this floor plan clear so I can use the information provided on it. I've been playing around with all the filters and adjustments on Photoshop and cannot get it to even a bare minimum state.

file:///C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/20%20-%20second%20floor.pdf

This is the image if you can open it

Comment: You will need to upload the file to an online storage site (like Dropbox, etc.) and the provide us with the link to that location in order for us to be able to view the image.  Right now it looks like you are providing a link to your hard drive.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=F72467D5CD70CC59&id=F72467D5CD70CC59%21450&parId=F72467D5CD70CC59%21160&o=OneUp

Okay hopefully this works, also I dont have high hopes for this image as its from 1920, but we will see hah

Comment: Sorry, when I try your link, I get an error message saying that the file is not available.  You probably need to adjust the permissions on that file to allow anyone with the link to view.  And you might be right about the image quality, but I have had luck clarifying old blueprints in the past, so it would be good to be able to see the actual file.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AlnMcM3VZyT3g0IRkmT1NVnmgeRK

I had a feeling it wouldn't work. Okay it says this is a shareable link so hopefully this works! Sorry I'm not use to OneDrive and that's where this image is

Comment: Do you still have access to the original documents? Are you able to rescan them? There doesn't seem to be any tangible information in the image you linked. I don't think any amount of tweaking or filtering is going to recover anything.

Comment: I did a bit of playing around in Photoshop, and although some settings allowed me to see "ghosts" of the floor plan, I wasn't able to do anything that made this readable on any level.  If anyone here is an expert at digital restoration, they might be able to do something with the file, but it is pretty bad.  Sorry about that.

Comment: No unfortunately I don't have access to the original. But thanks for trying, like I said I couldn't get much more than some walls to show up but with all the grainy pixels over the document it didn't do me much help!

Comment: [This is your floorplan as seen in the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXNkP.jpg). Other pages are blank. Please edit your question and include a screenshot. Otherwise nothing useful will be generated by the community.

Answer (score 1):

No amount of expertise in digital image processing or restoration is going to be able to extract anything meaningful from that image.

If you can get it to the point where you can partially distinguish what you know *should* be there then your best approach would be to print that out and then trace over it with a pen. Your eyes and brain are a lot cleverer at spotting relevent details and patterns than photoshop and you can adjust the angle and light or maybe place it on a lightbox. Whatever works. Then you could scan that back in and use it as a basis to redraw the plan digitally if that is what you ultimately need.